# Windows 10 CRITIAL SERVICE FAILED but boot in safe mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod

One friend laptop from one day to another started to give BSOD on normal boot, CRITIAL_SERVICE_FAILED.
Tried all repair options but none worked, and can't do a repair install on windows 10 if can't boot in normal mode.

BUT! I can boot in safe mode. So i tried to disable everything I could but still the same, BSOD on normal and boots okay in SAFE MODE.

Any idea? I'm trying not to reformat because it has special software.

Thanks.

Comment: *Any idea?* Boot in safe mode and look in a system journal what "critical service" failed.

Comment: @Akina By system journal I understand you mean event viewer, yes? If it's this I see critial error but unspecified.
Also I have activated boot log on boot options BUT is not creating the file, so I'm not seeing more options to search the problem.

Comment: The most common CRITIAL_SERVICE_FAILED sources are: some device drives (misconfiguration, damage, obsolete) or some software which install its own boot drivers/services, viruses, OS damage (files, registry), HDD errors, RAM errors. Is there a restore point with the data before the problem occures? try to revert to it...

Comment: you need to check Event viewer for system error when logged in in safe mode. This will reveal what exactly service failed.

Comment: Run in cmd: sfc /scannow

Comment: @Hardoman sfc is not working in safe mode... :(

Comment: Do a hard shut down while its trying to boot into windows, do this 3 times in a row and on the 4th try you will get a different options screen, from there you can do a refresh of the OS.

Comment: Can you post your minidump files? Find them in c:\windows\minidump . Zip them up, post the the zip to some file sharing place like dropbox or onedrive, and post the link. One of us (maybe me) should be able to figure out the failing service from the dump file(s).

Comment: Ok guys, yesterday I was running out of time so I ended reinstalling windows and all the special software because it was "urgent".
It's very frustrating because windows 10 doesn't let you to "reinstall" like the other versions does, althought it's never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help but question will end unsolved